# Internet explorer does not detect the images (width="70%")

Tags: internet-explorer, width

Internet explorer is not able to recognize my index page images. I create a random array of pictures that every time that the index is refresh a new picture will appear with a width="70%" (to be able to work for different devices). When i delete the width="70%", everything works good for all the different browsers; however, i would like to have a width that varies according on the screen size.

Answer (score 0):

Use css width
img.seventy{width:70%; box-sizing:border-box; -wekit-box-sizing:border-box; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; -o-box-sizing:border-box}